# How to improve code in Views on Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view

I have code in file views name: _result.html.erb, this file is rendered from file show.html.erb, both file in one folder

```
File _result.html.erb    
<% if @lesson.answers.at(f.index).is_correct %>
      <% if @lesson.answers.at(f.index).id == answer.id %>
        <li class="text-success">
          <%= f.radio_button :answer_id, answer.id, disabled: true %>
          <%= answer.content %>
        </li>
      <% else %>
        <li>
          <%= f.radio_button :answer_id, answer.id, disabled: true %>
          <%= answer.content %>
        </li>
      <% end %>
    <% else %>
      <% if @lesson.answers.at(f.index).id == answer.id %>
        <li class="text-danger">
          <%= f.radio_button :answer_id, answer.id, disabled: true %>
          <%= answer.content %>
        </li>
      <% else %>
        <li>
          <%= f.radio_button :answer_id, answer.id, disabled: true %>
          <%= answer.content %>
        </li>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

And I want to improve this code in file _result.html.erb for shorter, help me please!!!

```
File show.html
<% provide :title, t("start_lesson") %>
<h1><%= @course.name %></h1>
<h2><%= @course.description %></h2>
<h3><%= t "title_question" %></h3>

<% if @lesson.finished.present? %>
  <h4>
    <%= t "score" %>:
    <%= @lesson.results.is_correct_answers.count %> /
    <%= @lesson.words.count %>
  </h4>
<% end %>

<%= form_for [@course, @lesson] do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :results do |builder| %>
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
      <li>
        <%= "#{builder.index + 1}." %>
        <%= @words.at(builder.index).content %>
      </li>
      <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <% @words.at(builder.index).answers.each do |answer| %>
          <% if @lesson.finished.nil? %>
            <li>
              <%= answer.content %>
              <%= builder.radio_button :answer_id, answer.id %>
              <%= builder.hidden_field :word_id, value: answer.word.id %>
            </li>
          <% else %>
              <%= render "result", f: builder, answer: answer %>
          <% end %>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </ul>
  <% end %>
  <% if @lesson.finished.nil? %>
    <%= f.submit t("submit"), class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: when you say improve code, what do you exactly need?

Comment: In `_results.html.erb`, you are repeating the whole `<li>...</li>` block four times, even though only the class changes.

Comment: Minor improvement: instead of rendering the indices manually (`<%= "#{builder.index + 1}." %>`), you could use [`<ol>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ol).

Comment: Can you elaborate on the relationships between your models ? 
ex: a course has many lessons, a lesson has many answers, an answer has one result ? etc. 
Also, what is @words ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a code-rewrite exercise, so here goes:

**result.html.erb**

```
<% if @lesson.answers.at(f.index).id == answer.id %>
  <% if @lesson.answers.at(f.index).is_correct %>
    <li class="text-success">
  <% else %>
    <li class="text-danger">
  <% end %>
<% else %>
    <li>
<% end %>
      <%= f.radio_button :answer_id, answer.id, disabled: true %>
      <%= answer.content %>
    </li>
```

or the shorter (but much harder to read) version:

```
<li<% if @lesson.answers.at(f.index).id == answer.id %>class="<%= @lesson.answers.at(f.index).is_correct ? "text-success" : "text-danger" %>" <% end%>>
  <%= f.radio_button :answer_id, answer.id, disabled: true %>
  <%= answer.content %>
</li>
```

In the first example, the condition was inverted to take advantage of the fact that the `else` condition in both interior conditions was identical, and then using the conditions only to style the `<li>` node, since that was the only difference between the 4 blocks.

The second example goes further and does the conditional checks inline with the element, building the class attribute when necessary.  This is much harder to read at a glance, but is far more compact.

**show.html**

```
<% provide :title, t("start_lesson") %>
<h1><%= @course.name %></h1>
<h2><%= @course.description %></h2>
<h3><%= t "title_question" %></h3>

<% if @lesson.finished.present? %>
  <h4><%= "#{t 'score'}: #{@lesson.results.is_correct_answers.count} / #{@lesson.words.count} %></h4>
<% end %>

<%= form_for [@course, @lesson] do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :results do |builder| %>
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
      <li><%= "#{builder.index + 1}.#{@words.at(builder.index).content}" %></li>
      <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <% @words.at(builder.index).answers.each do |answer| %>
          <% if @lesson.finished.nil? %>
            <li>
              <%= answer.content %>
              <%= builder.radio_button :answer_id, answer.id %>
              <%= builder.hidden_field :word_id, value: answer.word.id %>
            </li>
          <% else %>
              <%= render "result", f: builder, answer: answer %>
          <% end %>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </ul>
  <% end %>
  <% if @lesson.finished.nil? %>
    <%= f.submit t("submit"), class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Most of the changes here are just using string interpolation to combine string elements that are otherwise multiple `<%= %>` blocks.

The larger loop portion that builds the list of answers has some possible issues.  For instance, the rendered result (when the lesson is not finished) is missing the `<li>` and `</li>` elements, so the answers are simply sitting as a blob of text within the enclosing `<ul>`.  In order to preserve that, in case it was intentional, most of the middle block remained.

However, this is probably not what you actually wanted, so this version fixes that and does a little more reorganization:

```
<% provide :title, t("start_lesson") %>
<h1><%= @course.name %></h1>
<h2><%= @course.description %></h2>
<h3><%= t "title_question" %></h3>

<% if @lesson.finished.present? %>
  <h4><%= "#{t 'score'}: #{@lesson.results.is_correct_answers.count} / #{@lesson.words.count} %></h4>
<% end %>

<%= form_for [@course, @lesson] do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :results do |builder| %>
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
      <li><%= "#{builder.index + 1}.#{@words.at(builder.index).content}" %></li>
      <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <% @words.at(builder.index).answers.each do |answer| %>
          <li>
            <% if @lesson.finished.nil? %>
              <%= answer.content %>
              <%= builder.radio_button :answer_id, answer.id %>
              <%= builder.hidden_field :word_id, value: answer.word.id %>
            <% else %>
              <%= render "result", f: builder, answer: answer %>
            <% end %>
          </li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </ul>
  <% end %>
  <% if @lesson.finished.nil? %>
    <%= f.submit t("submit"), class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

That's about the shortest this can be without collapsing the structure or just removing whitespace.  Each remaining element seems to have a purpose and is placed where it should be, without redundancy or over-complication.